# JQuery Drag can drag past the Containment element with auto-scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, draggable

I've been playing around with JQuery's drag and drop when i noticed I can drag out of the containment element when the window is too small and there's a scrollbar.  Basically with the below code, what you can do is make your window smaller until you have vertical scroll bars; then drag the inner div downwards until it goes past the outer div.

Anyone know a workaround or have encountered this problem elsewhere (maybe I'm doing it wrong)?  Currently I just disable the scroll option, but I'd rather it be able to scroll.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".draggable").draggable();
            $(".draggable").draggable("option", "containment", ".parentdraggable");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parentdraggable" style="border:1px solid black;min-width:400px;min-height:400px;">
        <div class="draggable" style="border:1px solid black">Hi</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I created a jsfiddle where one can see the behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/Sgoettschkes/PyyWG/ I'll play around a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set [scroll](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-scroll) to false. Sample Code: http://jsfiddle.net/Sgoettschkes/PyyWG/

I believe this solves the problem.

Comment: I know setting scroll to false is a workaround, however, like I said, I'd prefer to be able to scroll